# Using CloudFormation with Fn::ForEach - getting Duplicate error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to use [Fn::ForEach](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-foreach.html) and have looked at the [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-foreach-example-resource.html) but must be missing something. My goal is to have 3 entries in `SecurityGroupIngress`,  each with a different `SourceSecurityGroupId`.

My syntax is not correct. I get this error: `E0001 Error transforming template: Duplicate SourceSecurityGroupId while doing transformation`.

What am I missing?  I do have `Transform: 'AWS::LanguageExtensions'` at the top of my file.

```yaml
  MySqlIncomingSecurityGroups:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security for MySql RDS database
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          Description: Allow all outbound traffic by default
          IpProtocol: '-1'
      VpcId: vpc-123
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      'Fn::ForEach::Iterator':
        - CurrentSG
        - ["sg-1", "sg-2", "sg-3"]
        - SourceSecurityGroupId: "${CurrentSG}"
          Description: Allow all MySQL inbound
          IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 3306
          ToPort: 3306
```

Answer (score 2):

Define your [ingress rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-securitygroupingress.html) as top-level `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress` resources, instead of with the SG's `SecurityGroupIngress` property.

```yaml
'Fn::ForEach::Iterator':
    - CurrentSG
    - ["sg-1", "sg-2", "sg-3"]
    - 'IngressRule${CurrentSG}':
            Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress'
            Properties:
                SourceSecurityGroupId: "${CurrentSG}"
                Description: Allow all MySQL inbound
                IpProtocol: tcp
                FromPort: 3306
                ToPort: 3306
```

Looks like `Fn::ForEach` is designed to create *one resource per iteration* (when used in the `Resources` section), rather than being an arbitrary looping mechanism.